# CouchDB filter by date skips certain dates

Tags: couchdb, date-range

I am trying to get data from CouchDB between certain dates, and for most of it it works great, however certain dates are always skipped (even tho they are in range) and I don't get any data back for these dates.

However when I select only that specific date that I can't get in the range I get the results back. My curl is completely same in both range and specific date pick.

CouchDB function called (by_date)

```
  if(doc.type === 'employee')
  emit(doc.year + "-" + doc.month + "-" + doc.day, 
  {name:doc.name,
  email:doc.email, 
  department:doc.department,
  comment:doc.comment,
  nominator:doc.nominator, 
  values:doc.values, 
  type:doc.type, 
  team:doc.team
  });
}
```

**curl for range**

```
http://some-domain/some-database/_design/nominees/_view/by_date?&&startkey="2019-6-1"&&endkey="2019-8-16"
```

**curl for specific date**

```
http://some-domain/some-database/_design/nominees/_view/by_date?&&startkey="2019-8-2"&&endkey="2019-8-2"
```

Curl for rage returns all data except the one for 2019-8-2 even tho it is in range.

Curl for specific date returns data for 2019-8-2.

I want to be able to get this date in a selected range, but I am unsure what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are comparing dates as strings and not getting it right.

This means that "2019-08-2" < "2019-8-2", which isn't what you want.

You need to either zero-pad months and days correctly, or convert your dates to numbers, like epoch seconds, or emit a vector key:

```
emit([doc.year, doc.month, doc.day], ...);
```

(provided that .year .month .day are ints not strings in the original doc).

Comment: Hi xpqz, sorry I might have explained it badly, that was my typo...Curl for rage returns all data except the one for 2019-8-2 even tho it is in range.
Curl for specific date returns data for 2019-8-2.  The main problem is that the specific date is not picked up in the date range even tho it is within that range. So I don't get any records for that date back, however if I just put that date in range (1day) I get it back.